# Flutter - How to build an app with a generic homepage and optional sign in features

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an e-commerce app which has a generic homepage, which will list all products. I would then like the user to have an "account" page where they can either sign up or sign in.

When the user attempts to buy a product from the home screen, if they are not logged in they will need to before proceeding. I am not expecting someone to code this out for me (unless its a fairly straightforward ask) but can somebody advise on how to structure this project or better yet, link me to an example? I have trawled youtube looking for an example but all seem to have the user directed straight to the log in screen when launching the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn Firebase methods it will give you a server less cloud to stock your data and handle users information for account page.

I learn thanks to these guy videos https://youtu.be/FTju8w4zEno